# css not changing color on click

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

Do you know how on facebook, when you get notifications, the globe goes white, then you click on it to see them because your so happy. The color stays white on the globe unless you click out OR click the globe. I have the exact same situation. But when I click on the globe. My icon stays white. UNLESS I click out anywhere then it loses that white color.  I want to be able to click on the icon and then expect for the colour to go away.

scss:

```
.navbar-nav:not(.nav-badges) > li > a { font-weight: bold; }
.nav-badges {
  margin-left: 20px;
  & > li { height: 50px; }
  .dropdown > a:focus { outline: 0px none; }
  .dropdown-open {
    background-color: $dropdown-bg;
    & > a { color: $dropdown-link-color; }
    .dropdown-menu { display: block; }
  }
```

its pretty self explanitory, when icon is not clicked, then dropdown is in play, when it is clicked, dropdown dropdown-open is in play.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.

Comment: And if possible add a simple HTML sample, will make it easier.

Comment: If you have a sample, post it to JSFiddle (or another web-based editor of your choice) to demonstrate your issue to make simpler for others to jump in and help.

Answer (score 3):

So for sure facebook use some JavaScript tricks with ReactJs it's pretty straight forward.

But, I think you can use a CSS3 trick with a hidden checkbox and a label. [This trick looks to match perfectly your use case.](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

**It's bad for accessibility, it's tricky and you should probably go for some JavaScript.** But it's fun.

You can add a fixed overlay than also uncheck the hidden checkbox. Like this, when clicking outside the menu, the checkbox will be unchecked and your menu will go back to a normal state.

This is the only pure CSS implementation I can see. 
But again, use JavaScript for this kind of behaviour.